# Run .exe anywhere in cmd without PATH variable

Tags: cmd, exe, path-variables

This works (Notepad++):

```
C:\Anywhere> start notepad++ hello.txt
```

And this works (SoX for removing silence in sounds):

```
C:\Anywhere> sox in.wav out1.wav silence 1 0.1 1%
```

Yet, my **PATH** variable includes neither (would send on request).

How can I do this with my program?
To run from everywhere.

Also, why doesn't Notepad++ work without the `start` command?

(I did this workaround by putting the .exe in C:\ and then simply calling `C:\Anywhere> /myprogram` but I'm still curious about the above.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the indicated scenario where

- you can start applications from anywhere using the `start` command (or the windows `Run` dialog) without including its parent folder in `path` variable,
- but you can not start the application without the `start` command from any directory whithout including the full path to reach it (it is not in the `path`) or being located in the adecuated directory

the applications are included in the registry under the key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications
```

**note**: It is a [*"merged"* view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) showing the combined contents of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Applications
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications
```

If you are not administrator to change the local machine configuration, you can always modify your user registry information to include the applications you need.

**edited** There is a second place in registry that will allow to include an application in the registry to be executed using `start` command, `Run` dialog or from anything that uses the `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` API calls.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\
```